# What is causing this drywall bowing and hairline crack?

Tags: drywall

This has been going on for at least 4 months.  The drywall is bowing out in the middle and there are 3 hairline cracks running horizontally starting from where the bottom of staircase meets the wall.  The longest crack is about 8 feet long. We had some moisture from a different leak (fixed 3 months ago).   This is staircase between the 2nd and 3rd floors of my house.  The wall is just inside of the exterior wall (brick).  When I tap and push on the bowed part, it seems like it’s rock solid.[image]

Comment: Bowing out will require pictures of inside the wall/behind the drywall.  I assume this new and was not there before, which makes it concerning, especially on a three(plus?) story house.

Comment: Are you sure it has just began/you just noticed it 4 months ago?  Is it possible it has always been there/a bump from when the house was built and the light was just right to notice now?

Comment: I think it’s been happening slowly, maybe over the last year but I definitely noticed it more since dec ‘23.

Comment: This probably needs eyes on site.  Spending money on a structural engineer would make me sleep better.  Cracks in drywall is common from house settling.  Drywall bowing is not common, so either the wall was built not flat causing the bend, or something else.

Comment: I just checked with a level.  It looks like it’s only bowing out for about 6 inches where the wall meets the staircase.  Max bow is about 1/4 inch.  After that, it’s pretty close to level.

Comment: A 1/4 inch could be just a stud out of line, but that will be from when the house was built.  Can add marks and measure every few months.  If no change then it probably is okay.

Comment: A horizontal or vertical crack is usually harmless. Diagonal may indicate settling.